# How can I resize the screen size of an IFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` which is responsive depending on the `screen.width` and `screen.height` value. The problem is that even though it's in a small `<iframe>`, it thinks it's in a big screen. Inside the `<iframe>`, the value of `screen.height` is actually the size of the parent window, not the size of the `<iframe>` it's in, so things look bigger than they should be.

How can I get around this? I don't control the HTML file, but I can access it from the page it's contained in by using the `<iframe>` element's `contentWindow` or `contentDocument` property.

Comment: Does adding `width` and `height` attributes to your iframe fix the problem?

Comment: No. I tried that via CSS as well. The values of `screen.width` and `screen.height` are still different.

Comment: Did you write the iframe? What it's doing is correct. `screen` should always be the size of the screen, not the window. If the iframe referenced something like `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. If you wrote the iframe code you could change the references and accomplish this properly.

Comment: No, they're generated (from Adobe Captivate). I didn't right the code. Seems like I'm stuck. `window.inner...` gets the correct values.